# Confused about using grails paginate

Tags: java, html, grails, groovy, pagination

I am new to grails and I am a bit confused about how to use <g:paginate>.
I have a table and I want to set the max number of entrees to 10. Most of the examples I find online have used a List and have a set of jobs and services that help create the navigation. I am confused about this because I did not use a list in my controller. The total number of entrees is going through, but every entree is still displayed. If I click on page 2 or a 'next' button, it seems that my controller loses track of the sourceVolume that the user selected to generate this list.

For context - the first page the user sees prompts them to select a source volume - and from there a table is generated that shows a list of all of the entrees(snapshots) in the source volume.

my selectSnapshotVolume.gsp

```
<g:form class = "myForm" url="[controller:'Vaultrecovery', action:'doRecoveryConfirmation', method:'post']">
                <table class = "content-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select</th>
                            <th>Cluster</th>
                            <th>Vserver</th>
                            <th>Volume</th>
                            <th>SnapShot</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <g:each in="${destinationVolumes}" var="destinationVolume">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><g:radio name="snapshot" value="$destinationVolume.snapshot" required="true"></g: radio></td>
                                        <td>
                                            ${destinationVolume.cluster}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            ${destinationVolume.vserver}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            ${destinationVolume.volume}
                                        </td>
                                        <td><b>
                                                ${destinationVolume.snapshot}
                                            </b></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <g:hiddenField name="cluster" value="${destinationVolume.cluster}" />
                                    <g:hiddenField name="vserver" value="${destinationVolume.vserver}" />
                                    <g:hiddenField name="volume" value="${destinationVolume.volume}" />
                            </g:each>
                      </tbody>
                                </table> 
                                <div class = "centerMe">
                                  <div class="pagination">
                                    <g:paginate controller='Vaultrecovery' total="${entreeCount.total[0] ?: 0}" />
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "centerMeDescription">
                                  <g:submitButton class="submit " name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                </div>
</g:form>
```

and here is my controller. I do not have any services, jobs, or a domain class. I have also cut out parts of the controller that are irrelevant.

```
class VaultrecoveryController {

    def dataSource_model   // netapp_model
    def dataSource          // dataautomation
    def mailService
    File testFile = new File("/opt/tomcat/work/TEST")
    boolean TEST = testFile.exists()
    
    def index() { }
def selectSourceVolume() {
        log.info "Vaultrecovery Controller - selectSourceVolume"

        def foo = new Sql(dataSource_model)
        String SQL
        SQL = "SELECT distinct(name) FROM volume WHERE (name NOT LIKE '%_dest%' AND name NOT LIKE 'MDV%' AND name NOT LIKE '%\\_\\_%') ORDER BY name"
        log.info "Getting source volumes: " + SQL
        def sourceVolumes = foo.rows(SQL)
        [sourceVolumes: sourceVolumes]
    } // end selectSourceVolume


def selectSnapshotVolume() {
        log.info "Vaultrecovery Controller - selectSnapshotVolume"
       
        def sourceVolume = params.srcvolume
        log.info "SOURCE VOLUME IS: " + sourceVolume
        def foo = new Sql(dataSource)
        String SQL
        SQL = "SELECT cluster, vserver, volume, snapshot FROM netapp_vault WHERE volume LIKE '%" + sourceVolume + "%' ORDER BY snapshot"
        log.info SQL
        def destinationVolumes = foo.rows(SQL)

       
        SQL = "SELECT COUNT(cluster) as total FROM netapp_vault WHERE volume LIKE '%" + sourceVolume + "%' ORDER BY snapshot"

        def entreeCount = foo.rows(SQL);

        [sourceVolume: sourceVolume, destinationVolumes: destinationVolumes, entreeCount: entreeCount]
    } // end selectSnapshotVolume
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use the `params.offset` and `params.max` values that the `paginate` tag is causing to be passed to your controller.  If you don't use those, the tag isn't really of any real use.

Answer (score 0):

You lost the search criteria because the Prev or the Next button did not POST your Source Volume value back to the controller.

I had the same problem in my project.  Took me half the day to figure it out.  If you check the HTML what the Prev and the Next button is, they only POST back the Max and Offset values back to the controller.  Keep this in mind. This kind of project is state-less.  So, your action will reset back to the initial state.

```
<a href="/book/index?offset=10&max=10" class="nextLink">Next</a>
```

I use a private variable to store my last used search criteria. My action checks if the private variable has anything.  If so, it use the criteria from the private variable to run the SQL.  So, I will get the same records from the page before.  I then apply the Max and Offset to get the correct records.

Something like this:

```
class BookController {
   private String _searchString = ''

   def index() {
       _searchString = (params.searchString == null) ? _searchString : params.searchString
       bookList = Book.findAllByName(_searchString, params)
   }
}
```

params.searchString will be null because the Prev/Next button does not POST back the searchString.  If it is null, I grab the searchString from the private variable _searchString and use it in my dynamic finders.  I am lucky that Grails did not reset the _searchString variable when the Prev/Next calls the action.